# Setting "Active Profile" through Class AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

How would you set the "active profile" property when extending the class AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer ?

Comment: On which `ApplicationContext`? And how do you want to set it? Normally you can specify it with a JVM parameter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending which contexts' profiles you want to set, one way to do it is to override the

```
AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer#createRootApplicationContext()
```

and

```
AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer#createServletApplicationContext()
```

to set the active profiles in there. For example

```
@Override
protected WebApplicationContext createRootApplicationContext() {
    WebApplicationContext context = (WebApplicationContext)super.createRootApplicationContext();
    ((ConfigurableEnvironment)context.getEnvironment()).setActiveProfiles("profiles");
    return context;
}
```

**Note** the `super` call. You'll want this so that the super implementation actually creates the `WebApplicationContext` from your `@Configuration` classes (or any context you specified).