# Setting spring.profiles.active from Spring PropertyPlace holder

Tags: spring, properties, spring-profiles

In Spring 3.2 by default, Spring Environment object will resolve spring.profiles.active OS environment or -D JVM switch. I have a use case where I need to set the active profile from a common properties file. However, I am unable to make Environment resolve the active profile correctly.

Is there away to do that without using property placeholder?

Comment: No nor will a a `property-placeholder` work as the profiles are determined before that. You could create an `ApplicationContextInitializer` which reads your file and enabled the profiles before the context is actually loaded.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use your 'common' properties file as the Spring boot properties? i.e.  `--spring.config.location=file:/my/config.properties`

Comment: thanks Steve - are you referring to Spring boot here?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31369853/3517383) option for setting the active profile from a properties file, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20620765/3517383) one for reading from a VM parameter.